# Sending DataType As An Argument?

Tags: c#, methods, types

I'm trying to write a method that uses the following two arguments:

```
ColumnToSort
ColumnType
```

The reason I want to be able to do this is interpreting two things as a string can give a different result than comparing the same two things as a number. For example

```
String: "10" < "2"
Double: 10 > 2
```

So basically, I want to be able to send double or string datatype as a method argument, but I don't know how to do this, but it seems like something that should be possible in C#.

Addendum:

What I want my method to look like:

```
InsertRow(customDataObj data, int columnToSort, DataType dataType){
    foreach(var row in listView){
        var value1 = (dataType)listView.Items[i].SubItems[columnToSort];
        var value2 = (dataType)data.Something;
        //From here, it will find where the data object needs to be placed in the ListView and insert it
    }
}
```

How it will be called:

```
I think the above provides enough of an explanation to understand how it will be called, if there are any specific questions, let me know.
```

Comment: We're going to lead a lot more information than this.... what do your methods look like, how are you calling the code?

Comment: Give me a minute while I update the OP.

Comment: Sounds like you could probably make use of generics.  Something like YourFunc<T>(object OtherCriticalArgument).  Curious to see your revision and if that would apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Type`  as parameter type. like this

```
void foo(object o, Type t)
{
 ...
}
```

and call

```
Double d = 10.0;
foo(d, d.GetType());
```

or

```
foo(d, typeof(Double));
```

Comment: Ah, I see, you have to pass it using typeof(TYPE), I was trying Type.TYPE (that obviously didn't work).  Thanks! +1

Comment: Inside of "foo" when I try using t, I get: "The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".  My code: (t)listView.Items[i].SubItems[columnToSort].Text, I'm trying to cast my value.

Comment: In order to perform a dynamic cast at runtime, since the cast type cannot be known at compile-time (which is what you're describing), you will need to use runtime reflection.  There is an answer here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/fe14d396-bc35-4f98-851d-ce3c8663cd79, second post) that describes how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using generics.

```
InsertRow<T>(T data, int columnToSort){
    foreach(var row in listView){
        var value1 = (T)listView.Items[columnToSort].SubItems[columnToSort];
        var value2 = data;
        //From here, it will find where the data object needs to be placed in the ListView and insert it
        if(typeof(T)==typeof(string))
        {
          //do with something wtih data
        }
        else if(typeof(T)==typeof(int))
        {
          //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it, and let it figure out the type by itself.

```
int i=1;
InsertRow(i,/*column/*);
```

You may also want to restrict what T can be, for instance if you want to make sure it's a value type, `where T:struct`  [More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a reference to the Column itself like this:

```
 protected void DoSort(DataColumn dc)
      {
         string columnName = dc.ColumnName;
         Type type = dc.DataType;
      }
```

Cheers,
CEC